# Google App Script - How to use methods without defining their object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing the script behind a spreadsheet that has lots of durations on it in the format of (##:##.##) (ex 12:43.76). I need to write some code that converts this to just seconds. I wrote code that did the opposite, made seconds into that format. But when writing a custom formula for this, the .split method does not work.

```
function MTOS(input){
  String(input);
  if (typeof(input) != "string") {
    Logger.log("Not a string")}
  var array = input.split(":");
  Logger.log('The original string is: "' + input + '"');
var min = Number(array[0]);
var sec = Number(array[1]);
  Logger.log("min=" + min);
  Logger.log("sec=" + sec);
var MIN = min*60;
  Logger.log(MIN);
var ex = MIN+sec;
  Logger.log(ex);
return ex;
}
```

This is what I have in the script editor. The input is the parameter from the spreadsheet when I write the formula in the sheet itself (ex - =MTOS(3:23.53)). When I run the function in the script editor, it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot call method "split" of undefined. (line 5, file "MTOS")" and in sheets, it returns "Error : Result was not a number." I understand that this is happening because input is not defined in the function itself, so .split cannot work. But how else can I write the custom formula for sheets?

Thank you.

Comment: Duplicate the cell and apply a number / general format to it, rather than use a custom formula.

Comment: Is there no way to fix what I have already? Formatting is my only option?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me: (Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the question).

```
function MTOS(input){
  var iA = input.split(":");
  var min = Number(iA[0]);
  var sec = Number(iA[1]);
  Logger.log('Seconds=%s',min * 60 + sec);
}
```

Comment: This looks like it would work to me, and if I define input as a random number inside the function, it works (ex  - input = "1:24.65";). But when I write =MTOS(_somenumber_) it returns a blank cell, with nothing in it and no error message.

Comment: I assumed that the input was a string of the form "##:##.##"